# Node Group not being saved in Node Presets

Tags: materials, node-editor, add-on, shader-nodes

I would like to use the add-on *Node Preset* that is included in *Blender* to speed up my work.

To do this, I have created a node group, and saved it to a file.
This file is located where I have my node presets.
But *Blender* does not recognize it for some reason.

How can I get *Blender* to recognize these individual node groups so I can use them?

Comment: They say they fixed the asset browser to work with Node groups and collections ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKZLlCZbDnI

Comment: Do the names of your node group coincidentally start with an underscore? These nodes are not taken over.

Comment: It works now! I didn't change anything so it must have been a bug.